# How to select Google Web Fonts (via @font-your-face) from drop down in SWeaver UI?

Tags: 7, theming

I am using the SWeaver module for "in-situ" editing of the (CSS) styles of elements on pages i.e. by "in-situ" I mean *within* Drupal style changes (instead of raw editing the theme files CSS via FTP).

Sweaver provides the means to change the font of the text on a page via it's pop up user interface panel that resides at the base of the page.

I am trying to get the Google Web Fonts listed in the drop down menu of available fonts but this does not show. Apparently, Sweaver provides support for various web font foundries including Google Web Fonts via @font-your-face. So I've gone into the Admin/Configuration for @font-your-face and enabled Google Web Fonts and enables the fonts I want but they don't appear in the Sweaver drop down list.

Can someone supply a step-by-step guide to getting Google Web Fonts to appear in the drop down list of fonts in Sweaver

References:

- http://drupal.org/project/sweaver
- http://www.google.com/webfonts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a solution in the issue queue for SWeaver; several other users have reported similar problems. 2 things to try would be to clear the cache and to install the latest development version.

http://drupal.org/project/issues/sweaver?text=%40font-your-face&status=All